# create derived column and sample from distribution when missing

Tags: r

I try to impute missing values in one column by sampling from a given discrete distribution. I chose gender as a simple example. This is my attempt:

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(42)

df <- data.frame(
    gender = c("f", "m", "m", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
)
df

df <- df %>%
    mutate(
        derived_gender_of_casualty = ifelse(
                            is.na(gender)
                            , sample(x = c("m", "f"), prob = c(0.9, 0.1))
                            , as.character(gender))
    )
df
```

It creates:

[image]

However, it does not look right. The genders are uniformly distributed. I would expect there to be more males given the probability of 0.9 (this is not meant to be controversial - in hisight I should have picked another example haha!!!).

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You need to add `size=` to your `sample(.)` call. Without it, it is sampling a vector of length 2, returning a vector of length 2, and then having that vector recycled *uniformly*. Try `if_else(is.na(gender), sample(c("m", "f"), size = n(), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.9, 0.1)), gender)`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see what `sample(x = c("m", "f"), prob = c(0.9, 0.1))` returns

```
sample(x = c("m", "f"), prob = c(0.9, 0.1))
#[1] "m" "f"
```

Try this multiple times, do you see any change? Maybe the order gets changed but do you see any effect of 0.9 or 0.1 ? Let's repeat this for 100 times and count number of times `'m'` and `'f'` occur.

```
table(replicate(100, sample(x = c("m", "f"), prob = c(0.9, 0.1))))

#  f   m 
#100 100
```

Still the ratio is the same. By default `sample` has `replace = FALSE` and when you don't mention the `n`, it is same as length of the vector passed so the probability does not matter here. The reason why you get such an output is because `sample(x = c("m", "f"), prob = c(0.9, 0.1))` returns two values with both `m` and `f` and the same value is recycled throughout.

---

**Solution**

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)
df %>%
  mutate(
    derived_gender_of_casualty = ifelse(
      is.na(gender)
      , sample(x = c("m", "f"), n(), prob = c(0.9, 0.1), replace = TRUE)
      , as.character(gender))
  )

#   gender derived_gender_of_casualty
#1       f                          f
#2       m                          m
#3       m                          m
#4    <NA>                          m
#5    <NA>                          f
#6    <NA>                          m
#7    <NA>                          m
#8    <NA>                          m
#9    <NA>                          m
#10   <NA>                          m
#11   <NA>                          f
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, using `sum(is.na(gender))` returns a length shorter than the length required, and `base::ifelse` is silently recycling (busting the `prob=`). If you switch to `dplyr::if_else`, this fails (for good reason). Best to just use `n()` instead of `sum(.)`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks, updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `rowwise` in your chain should do it:

```
df <- df %>%
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(
    derived_gender_of_casualty = ifelse(
      is.na(gender)
      , sample(x = c("m", "f"), prob = c(0.9, 0.1))
      , as.character(gender))
  )
df
```

Here's a little experiment to show that it works.  I make `df` have 1000 rows all missing on `gender`.  The imputed data has Pr(M) approximately = 0.9.

```
set.seed(42)

df <- data.frame(
  gender = rep(NA, 1000)
)
df

df <- df %>%
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(
    derived_gender_of_casualty = ifelse(
      is.na(gender)
      , sample(x = c("m", "f"), size = 1, prob = c(0.9, 0.1))
      , as.character(gender))
  )
mean(df$derived_gender_of_casualty == "m")
#[1] 0.899
```

Comment: thanks i saw this when googling but did not see its significance

Comment: This is both inefficient (`rowwise`) and in a sense wrong, because `sample(.)` is returning length-2 for everything but `ifelse` is silently ignoring that part. If you switch to `dplyr::if_else`, this fails, for good reason.

Comment: DaveArmstrong, I suggested an edit to your answer that addressed the missing `size=`, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans.  I appreciate the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

A base R option:

```r
set.seed(42)

df <- data.frame(
  gender = c("f", "m", "m", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
)

  df$gender[is.na(df$gender)] <-  sample(x = c("m", "f"), 
                                         size = sum(is.na(df$gender)), 
                                         prob = c(0.9, 0.1), 
                                         replace = TRUE)
  
  df
#>    gender
#> 1       f
#> 2       m
#> 3       m
#> 4       f
#> 5       f
#> 6       m
#> 7       m
#> 8       m
#> 9       m
#> 10      m
#> 11      m
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>